# Do I qualify for a Dutch passport through my grandfather?

Tags: citizenship, netherlands, passport, dutch-citizens, south-africa

I might have all of this completely wrong, so I am sorry if that is the case. As far as I know, you can apply for British citizenship if you have a British grandparent. Is the same true for the Netherlands? My grandfather was born in the Netherlands, then moved to South Africa. Do I qualify for a Dutch passport?

Comment: Did either of your parents have Dutch citizenship? Do a search on the netherlands tag here. There have been a lot of questions about trying to get Dutch citizenship via ancestors.

Comment: The [answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/20455/2440) by [jason.kaisersmith](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/19540/jason-kaisersmith) is basically correct.  There are lots of little loopholes, one of which is that independent naturalization of a minor does not cause loss of nationality.  Transmission of nationality was also formerly possible only by fathers, so it matters whether this is your maternal or paternal grandfather.  To figure it all out, you need to know when your grandfather naturalized in South Africa (if ever), when your parent and you were born, ...

Comment: ... whether anyone has lived outside South Africa and if so when and where, whether anyone was working for the UN or a similar organization of which the Netherlands is a member, and probably a few other factors that don't come to mind just now.

Comment: "British grandparent" doesn't mean you can get British citizenship. You get British citizenship if one parent is British citizen (Father or mother have British parents and are born in the UK), or a parent is "British citizen by decent", that is British parents and not born in the UK, and you yourself are born in the UK.

Answer (score 3):

According to Dutch nationality law you can qualify for Dutch citizenship via your parents if they were Dutch at the time of your birth.  The nationality of your grandparents is not relevant.

So if neither of your parents were Dutch citizens at the time of your birth, then you do not qualify for nationality via descent.

Also, Dutch nationality law is very strict on dual nationality, and it is only allowed under some circumstances, and in some cases is automatically lost if the person acquires citizenship of a foreign country, or if a dual national at birth and lives outside of the Netherlands in adulthood.

You need to look into it given your exact circumstances.  There are plenty of other posts on here about if you qualify via your parents.

More details can be found here:
https://ind.nl/en/dutch-citizenship/Pages/by-birth-or-acknowledgement.aspx
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_nationality_law#Loss_of_Dutch_citizenship

BTW:  Your statement about British nationality via your Grandparents is also not correct.